# Fluentd filter to exclude key with empty value

Tags: regex, fluentd

I want exclude a row that have serive_name empty `"service_name":""`.
Here is my fluentd conf

```
## match tag=debug.** and dump to console
<match debug.**>
  @type stdout
</match>
<source>
  @type tail
  path  /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0-wkr-1/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/tmp/wso2carbon.log.pos
  tag debug.wso2.esb
  format /^([TID:]* [^ ]* [^ ]* \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\]) ([^ ]* (?<level>[^ ]*))([^***]*[^=]*[^ ]*(?<service_name>[^,]*)[^=]*[^ ]*(?<step>[^,]*)[^ ]*[^=]*[^ ]*(?<message_id>[^,]*))/
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
#  keep_time_key true
</source>
```

Here is the log out-put

```
2017-08-21 09:57:10 +0700 debug.wso2.esb: {"level":"INFO","service_name":" SA_VasGWLogSeq","step":" before vasgwInsertlog","message_id":" urn:uuid:2046f0ed-690d-47b1-aa86-d4a71c021a74"}
2017-08-21 09:57:10 +0700 debug.wso2.esb: {"level":"INFO","service_name":"","step":"","message_id":""}
2017-08-21 09:57:10 +0700 debug.wso2.esb: {"level":"INFO","service_name":" SA_VasGWLogSeq","step":" after vasgwInsertlog","message_id":" urn:uuid:2046f0ed-690d-47b1-aa86-d4a71c021a74"}
2017-08-21 10:16:10 +0700 debug.wso2.esb: {"level":"INFO","service_name":" SERVICE_NAME","step":" Before - SA_ServiceApiDSEp","message_id":" urn:uuid:39e0ecc1-dda5-4cd9-91fc-90e7ed4f5233"}
```

I want to exclude below row. How to do that?

```
{"level":"INFO","service_name":"","step":"","message_id":""}
```

<del>The second question is why I have a space before value `"service_name":" SERVICE_NAME"`, when I try on [Fluentular I get a nice output without space](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%5E%28%5BTID%3A%5D*+%5B%5E+%5D*+%5B%5E+%5D*+%5C%5B%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%29%5C%5D%29+%28%5B%5E+%5D*+%28%3F%3Clevel%3E%5B%5E+%5D*%29%29%28%5B%5E***%5D*%5B%5E%3D%5D*%5B%5E+%5D*%28%3F%3Cservice_name%3E%5B%5E%2C%5D*%29%5B%5E%3D%5D*%5B%5E+%5D*%28%3F%3Cstep%3E%5B%5E%2C%5D*%29%5B%5E+%5D*%5B%5E%3D%5D*%5B%5E+%5D*%28%3F%3Cmessage_id%3E%5B%5E%2C%5D*%29%29&input=TID%3A+%5B-1234%5D+%5B%5D+%5B2017-08-21+09%3A49%3A39%2C710%5D++INFO+%7Borg.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator%7D+-++To%3A+%2Ftoolstest%2Fv1%2Flogger%2C+MessageID%3A+urn%3Auuid%3A4c678d37-9eb5-415a-9568-063ca3fca578%2C+Direction%3A+request%2C+***+%3D+SERVICE_NAME%2C+step+%3D+Before+-+SA_ServiceApiDSEp%2C+uuid+%3D+urn%3Auuid%3A4c678d37-9eb5-415a-9568-063ca3fca578%2C+Envelope%3A+%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%271.0%27+encoding%3D%27utf-8%27%3F%3E%3Csoapenv%3AEnvelope+xmlns%3Asoapenv%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F05%2Fsoap-envelope%22%3E%3Csoapenv%3ABody%3E%3Cresponse+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fws.apache.org%2Fns%2Fsynapse%22%3Eurn%3Auuid%3A4c678d37-9eb5-415a-9568-063ca3fca578%3C%2Fresponse%3E%3C%2Fsoapenv%3ABody%3E%3C%2Fsoapenv%3AEnvelope%3E+%7Borg.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator%7D&time_format=%25Y-%25m-%25d+%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S).</del>

I have solved the second quest by add a space to regex. e.g. change

`[^=]*[^ ]*(?<service_name>[^,]*)` to `[^=]*[^ ]* (?<service_name>[^,]*)`.

---

But I don't know **how to write a filter to exclude a record by key_name that have empty value like `"service_name":""`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I cannot find a solution to exclude record that key have empty value, I use the reverse solution. I use grep to keep record with specified key-value. See my Fluentd configuration below.

Fluentd on each WSO2 node.

```
#############################################################################################
# Fluentd Configuration File                                                                #
#                                                                                           #
# In v1 configuration, type and id are @ prefix parameters.                                 #
# @type and @id are recommended. type and id are still available for backward compatibility #
#############################################################################################

################################
#            Source            #
################################
## built-in TCP input
## $ echo <json> | fluent-cat <tag>
<source>
  @type forward
  @id forward_input

  port 24224
</source>

# Listen DRb for debug
<source>
  @type debug_agent
  @id debug_agent_input

  bind 127.0.0.1
  port 24230
</source>

# HTTP input
# http://localhost:8888/<tag>?json=<json>
#<source>
#  @type http
#  @id http_input

#  port 8888
#</source>

# Listen HTTP for monitoring
# http://localhost:24220/api/plugins
# http://localhost:24220/api/plugins?type=TYPE
# http://localhost:24220/api/plugins?tag=MYTAG
<source>
  @type monitor_agent
  @id monitor_agent_input

  port 24220
</source>

<source>
  @type tail

  path /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0-wkr-1/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
  pos_file /cc/fluent/wso2carbon.log.pos
  tag wso2.esb.service.test
  format /^([TID:]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+ \[(?<time>[^\]]+)\]) ([^***]+[^=]+[^ ]+(?<transaction_id>[^,]*)[^=]+[^ ]+(?<service_name>[^,]*)[^=]+[^ ]+(?<data>[^,]*))/
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  keep_time_key true
</source>

<source>
  @type tail

  path /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0-wkr-1/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
  pos_file /cc/fluent/wso2carbon.log.pos
  tag wso2.esb.ne.surepay
  format /^([TID:]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+ \[(?<time>[^\]]+)\]) ([^***]+[^=]+[^ ]+(?<service_name>[^,]*)[^=]+[^ ]+(?<transaction_id>[^,]*)[^<?]+(?<payload>[^{]*))/
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  keep_time_key true
</source>

<source>
  @type tail

  path /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0-wkr-1/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
  pos_file /cc/fluent/wso2carbon.log.pos
  tag wso2.esb.surepay.trigger
  format /^([TID:]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+ \[(?<time>[^\]]+)\]) ([^*]+[^=]+[^ ]+(?<client_ip>[^,]*)[^=]+[^ ]+(?<service_name>[^,]*)[^=]+[^ ]+(?<req_id>[^,]*)[^=]+[^ ]+(?<content_massage>[^,]*)[^=]+[^ ]+)/
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  keep_time_key true
</source>


###########################
#        Filter           #
###########################
<filter wso2.esb.service.**>
  @type grep

  <regexp>
    key     service_name
    pattern ^\sNew
  </regexp>
</filter>

<filter wso2.esb.service.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby

  <record>
    data ${record["data"].strip.split(";").each_slice(2).to_h.to_json}
  </record>
</filter>

<filter wso2.esb.service.**>
  @type parser

  format json
  key_name data
</filter>

<filter wso2.esb.ne.surepay>
  @type grep

  <regexp>
    key     service_name
    pattern ^\sNE_SurePay
  </regexp>
</filter>

<filter wso2.esb.ne.surepay>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby

  <record>
    service_name ${record["service_name"].strip!}
    transaction_id ${record["transaction_id"].strip!}
    payload ${record["payload"].strip!}
  </record>
</filter>

<filter wso2.esb.surepay.trigger>
  @type grep

  <regexp>
    key     service_name
    pattern ^\sSurePayPassiveTrigger
  </regexp>
</filter>

<filter wso2.esb.surepay.trigger>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby

  <record>
    client_ip ${record["client_ip"].strip!}
    service_name ${record["service_name"].strip!}
    req_id ${record["req_id"].strip!}
    content_massage ${record["content_massage"].strip!}
  </record>
</filter>


###########################
#        Output           #
###########################
## Debug
## match tag=debug.** and dump to console
<match debug.**>
  @type stdout
  @id stdout_output
</match>

## ESB Service Log
## match tag=wso2.esb.**. Forward to Fluentd Collector (, stdout for debug) and write to file
<match wso2.esb.**>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type forward
    @id forward_output
    buffer_path /cc/fluent/buffer/fluentd.forward
    buffer_type file
    flush_interval 10
    send_timeout 60
    heartbeat_type tcp
    heartbeat_interval 20

    <server>
      host 172.16.100.243
      port 24224
    </server>
    ## If have sencondary fluentd server for fail-over, enable <secondary> block
    # <secondary>
    #   <server>
    #     host 192.168.0.12
    #   </server>
    # </secondary>
  </store>

  <store>
    @type file
    @id file_output

    path  /cc/fluent/log/wso2
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H
    time_slice_wait   10m
    time_format       %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

Fluentd collector (collecting data from all fluentd on each node):

```
#############################################################################################
# Fluentd Server Configuration File                                                                #
#                                                                                           #
# In v1 configuration, type and id are @ prefix parameters.                                 #
# @type and @id are recommended. type and id are still available for backward compatibility #
#############################################################################################

################################
#            Source            #
################################
## built-in TCP input
## $ echo <json> | fluent-cat <tag>
<source>
  @type forward
  @id forward_input

  port 24224
</source>

# Listen DRb for debug
<source>
  @type debug_agent
  @id debug_agent_input

  bind 127.0.0.1
  port 24230
</source>

# HTTP input
# http://localhost:8888/<tag>?json=<json>
#<source>
#  @type http
#  @id http_input

#  port 8888
#</source>

# Listen HTTP for monitoring
# http://localhost:24220/api/plugins
# http://localhost:24220/api/plugins?type=TYPE
# http://localhost:24220/api/plugins?tag=MYTAG
<source>
  @type monitor_agent
  @id monitor_agent_input

  port 24220
</source>


###########################
#        Filter           #
###########################
# <filter wso2.esb.service.**>
#   @type grep

#   <regexp>
#     key     service_name
#     pattern ^New
#   </regexp>
# </filter>

# <filter wso2.esb.ne.surepay>
#   @type grep

#   <regexp>
#     key     service_name
#     pattern ^NE_SurePay
#   </regexp>
# </filter>

# <filter wso2.esb.ne.surepay>
#   @type grep

#   <regexp>
#     key     service_name
#     pattern ^SurePayPassiveTrigger
#   </regexp>
# </filter>


###########################
#        Output           #
###########################
## Debug
## match tag=debug.** and dump to console
<match debug.**>
  @type stdout
  @id stdout_output
</match>

## ESB Service Log
## match tag=wso2.esb.service.** and insert into database (, stdout for debug) and write to file
<match wso2.esb.**>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type sql
    buffer_path /cc/fluent/buffer/fluentd.sql
    buffer_type file
    flush_interval 10

    host {ORACLE_HOST}
    port 1521
    database {ORACLE_DATABASE}
    adapter oracle_enhanced
    username {ORACLE_USERNAME}
    password {ORACLE_PADDWORD}

    <table>
      table {TABLE_NAME}
      column_mapping 'insert_date:insert_date,transaction_id:transaction_id,service_name:service_name,process_step:process_step,msisdn:msisdn,command:command,transaction_type:transaction_type,action:action,service_price:service_price,subcriber_type:subcriber_type,transaction_status:transaction_status,notification:notification,remark:remark,vas_error_code:vas_error_code,client_username:client_username,client_ip:client_ip,api_url:api_url,api_method:api_method,nei_name:nei_name,nei_error_code:nei_error_code,server_host:server_host'
      # This is the default table because it has no "pattern" argument in <table>
      # The logic is such that if all non-default <table> blocks
      # do not match, the default one is chosen.
      # The default table is required.
    </table>

    <table wso2.esb.service.test>
      table {TABLE_NAME}
      column_mapping 'insert_date:insert_date,transaction_id:transaction_id,service_name:service_name,process_step:process_step,msisdn:msisdn,command:command,transaction_type:transaction_type,action:action,service_price:service_price,subcriber_type:subcriber_type,transaction_status:transaction_status,notification:notification,remark:remark,vas_error_code:vas_error_code,client_username:client_username,client_ip:client_ip,api_url:api_url,api_method:api_method,nei_name:nei_name,nei_error_code:nei_error_code,server_host:server_host'
    </table>

    <table wso2.esb.ne.surepay>
      table {TABLE_NAME}
      column_mapping 'time:insert_date,transaction_id:transaction_id,service_name:service_name,payload:payload'
    </table>

    <table wso2.esb.surepay.trigger>
      table {TABLE_NAME}
      column_mapping 'time:insert_date,client_ip:client_ip,service_name:service_name,req_id:req_id,content_massage:content_massage'
    </table>
  </store>

  <store>
    @type file
    path  /cc/fluent/log/service
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H
    time_slice_wait   10m
    time_format       %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

**NOTE:** I use frontd to tail log from WSO2 and then insert into Oracle Database.

**PLATFORM:** RedHat 7, ruby 2.4.1p111, fluentd 0.12.40, activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.8.2), ruby-oci8 (2.2.5), fluent-plugin-sql (0.6.1).

**UPDATE**
I have publish all configuration and installation detail on GitHub
https://github.com/oemdaro/fluent-oracle-example

Answer (score 7):

It seems like a fairly trivial use of the `grep` filter plugin's [`exclude`](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/grep#less-than-exclude-greater-than-directive) directive.

Matching an empty message and excluding it using the "start" (`^`), followed by nothing and end (`$`) can be done by the following.

```
<filter **>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key service_name
    pattern /^$/
    # or, to exclude all messages that are empty or include only white-space:
    # pattern /^\s*$/
  </exclude>
</filter>
```

Note that there was a change to the regex notation between 0.12 and 1.x (now uses leading and trailing slashes).